# Is this a JDK thread BUG

Tags: java, multithreading

Here is my code:

```
public class Test {

private static /*volatile*/ int count = 0; 

public static void main(String[] args) { 
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while(true){
                //System.out.println(1); //①
                if(count==10){
                    System.out.println("I'm over");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
    //run ten thread
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {             System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()+","+Math.random());
                count = count+1;                    
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

When I use jdk7 it prints "I'm over" of course the thread is over, but when I use jdk8 the thread never gets there.

It looks like always waiting,of course never print "I'm over". 
Why? is this a jdk BUG?

Comment: What happens when the writing threads push `count` from 9 to 11 before your reading thread checks for 10? Note that there are little guarantees on how unrelated threads are executed (i.e. which order, etc.) so it's most probably NOT a bug.

Comment: please grab a book about concurrency before you attempt to do anything with threads

Comment: What both Thomas said. When you need to ask, "Is this basic feature on a mature and widely used product simply broken, or is it just me making a huge mistake", it's always the later.

Comment: but why ? it's the same code,why have diffent result?just change jdk7 to jdk8?

Comment: When you write broken code, it can be broken in different ways between JDK versions. The only way to ensure that it works the same way always is to write **correct** code.

Comment: well When I swap the two code ，I‘s ok....Amazing!!!

Comment: No, it's not ok. The code is still broken if you swap the pieces of code. You need to make `count` `volatile` (or provide another way to make sure that the changes are visible between threads).

Comment: You, you can see my comment out the code, I know that writing is wrong, or that there is hidden danger, but I just want to say on the matter, the code I, why when operating at JDK7 end, but jdk8 did not, I just want to know only the code for so, why?

Comment: "but why ? it's the same code,why have diffent result?" - because multi-threaded code with race conditions can behave differently on different runs. Subtle differences in the JDK versions may lead to one possible behaviour being more likely than another.

Comment: Whenever you read or write from attributes or properties that can be accessed from multiple threads, you should use a lock to make sure your access is threadsafe. In this case, your line incrementing the count property may run in parallel on several threads and you'll never reach the "10" you're waiting for. It isn't one atomic operation, it is three operations (read, increment, store). For example, thread 2 may have already read the current count before thread 1 had a chance to store the incremented value.

Comment: Give me the same question, but the point of exaggeration, System.out.print (1), why JDK7 can but jdk8 not, the same reason

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not thread-safe, which means that the semantics of the program is not defined. This is specified in the Java Language Specification. In this case the JVM might behave differently depending on its version, the machine you are using, the operating system, or the weather outside. It is **not** a bug in the JVM.

Taken from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5:

> A program must be correctly synchronized to avoid the kinds of counterintuitive behaviors that can be observed when code is reordered. The use of correct synchronization does not ensure that the overall behavior of a program is correct. However, its use does allow a programmer to reason about the possible behaviors of a program in a simple way; the behavior of a correctly synchronized program is much less dependent on possible reorderings. Without correct synchronization, very strange, confusing and counterintuitive behaviors are possible.

Answer (score 0):

The java memory model could have been changed between the versions. We have to read the specs to be sure. Anyway my guess is the line `count = count+1;`     in your for loops is not atomic and the multiple threads overwrite it and prevent it from  reaching 10.